# ¿Por qué este código funciona, pero no como deberia?

Tags: c, fgets

Hoy he estado investigando sobre la funcion `fgets()` de C. El prototipo de la función es este:

```
char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream);
```

Siguiendo esto, he estado haciendo un programa para ver hasta que punto puede llegar la función sin fallar.

El código es el siguiente (He eliminado el `#include <stdio.h>` para acortar el código):

```
int main(void){
    char full_name[10];
    printf("Enter your full name: ");
    fgets(full_name, 50, stdin);
    printf("Hellouda, %s", full_name);
    return 0;
}
```

En teoría, debería tener un error de ejecución en la línea 4, debido a el overflow del buffer, pero en vez de eso, *amplia* la string `full_name` para forzar que entren todos los caracteres.

Así si escribo:

```
Enter your full name: Alberto Fernandez Melendez
```

La salida es:

```
Hellouda Alberto Fernandez Melendez
```

¿Alguien sabe a que se puede deber este *error*?

Muchas gracias y saludos :)

Comment: Por qué piensas que debería haber un error en esa línea? Según lo que veo sobre la definición de la función, se leerá (en este caso de `stdin`) hasta que escribas 49 caracteres, o escribas un `new line` o el archivo termine. Así que con los valores que colocaste con ese nombre, no deberìa haber problema.

Comment: Pero en teoría, se guarda en `full_name`, lo cual es imposible, porque se desbordaría, dado que solo caben 9 caracteres

Comment: Ahora si entiendo la pregunta. Eso lo sabes tú, no lo sabe fgets.... y _casualmente_ la data (mejor dicho, memoria) que está luego de esos 10 caracteres no está reservada ni estás rompiendo nada.... el programa puede ser que compile y corra bien... pero ciertamente tienes un buffer overflow al que alguien le podría sacar provecho _o_ tu programa podría fallar de formas inesperadas en momentos inesperados por la misma razón.

Comment: ¿Qué data dices?

Comment: ... todo eso para decir: es parte de tu responsabilidad como desarrollador en C asegurarte de que no estés introduciendo un bug como ese en tu código.... no necesariamente el programa va a fallar con lo que hiciste (como acabas de ver, no falla), pero no está correcto. Tienes un error de buffer overflow escondido en tu programa.

Comment: Ah vale vale, ahora lo entiendo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Desbordar el búfer, es [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido). El programa puede funcionar como puede fallar. Así que el resultado es indefinido, puede ser cualquiera.

Por ejemplo, las consecuencias de desbordar el búfer podrían ser:

- Sobrescribir la memoria del propio programa (esto es difícil depurarlo).
- [Violacion de acceso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso), significa, intentar escribir (*o leer*) en una dirección que al programa no le *pertenece*. Si el sistema operativo tiene [protección de memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protecci%C3%B3n_de_memoria), no permitirá que accedas a la memoria, por ende, hará que el [proceso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proceso_(inform%C3%A1tica)) actual aborte de forma inmediata.

Para evitar el desbordamiento de búfer, deberías especificar la longitud del array en la función `fgets`:

```c
fgets(full_name, sizeof full_name, stdin);
```

**Actualización:**

> > Pero, estoy depurando el programa, y la función me está ampliando el tamaño del string..

Modifiqué el programa para facilitar la explicación:

```c
int main(void)
{
    char id[6] = {0};
    char str[5] = {0};
    printf("Enter your string: ");
    //Asumamos que el usuario ingresa "Hello World"
    fgets(str, 11, stdin);
    printf("Hellouda, %s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Ahora vamos asumir que el *array* `str` y `id` está reflejado así en memoria:

```c
---------Buffer array STR-------- ---------- Buffer array ID ------
0x01  0x02  0x03   0x04   0x05   | 0x06  0x07  0x08  0x09  0xA  0xB
0      0     0      0      0        0     0     0     0     0    0
```

Cuando se ejecute esta función:

```c
fgets(str, 11, stdin);
```

La función `fgets` podrá leer hasta `N-1` caracteres (en este caso, leería hasta `10` caracteres, puesto la función debe dejar un espacio para el caracter nulo). Ahora, supongamos que esta función sobrescribe la memoria del propio programa:

```c
---------Buffer array STR-------- ---------- Buffer array ID ------
0x01  0x02  0x03   0x04   0x05   | 0x06  0x07  0x08  0x09  0xA  0xB
H      e     l      l      o        w     o     r     l     d    \0
```

Como verás, el caracter nulo quedó en la dirección `0xB`. Así que si llegara a ejecutar esto:

```c
printf("%d", strlen(str));
```

La función `strlen` recorrerá el *array* hasta encontrar el caracter nulo. Como verás, la función `fgets` no amplia el tamaño del array `str`, para nada. El resultado que muestra en pantalla **es la longitud de la cadena que ingresó el usuario.**

Esto en la práctica es complicado solucionarlo, así que debes tener mucho cuidado con el buffer overflow.

Comment: Pero, estoy depurando el programa, y la función me está ampliando el tamaño del string ??? :0

Comment: @ByRussX Como sabes si el tamaño del array se esta ampliando? La longitud `full_name` es fijo, no se lo puede ampliar. La funcion `fgets` no amplia nada.

Comment: He estado haciendo pruebas usando `printf();` y `strlen();`

Comment: @ByRussX Algo estas haciendo mal. Solo imprime el tamaño del array de esta forma: `printf("%d", sizeof full_name);`, muestra el tamaño de bytes que ocupa todo el array. El tamaño nunca cambia, seguira siendo el mismo.

Comment: `printf("%d", strlen(full_name));`

Comment: @ByRussX Lo que pasa es que `printf` y `strlen` leen hasta que encuentran un `\0`. Y el \0 ya esta pasado de el tamaño del array

Comment: @ByRussX he editado la respuesta, espero te sirva!

Answer (score 3):

Modifiques tu programa agregando la variable `otra_area` luego de `full_name`. Esta variable la inicializo con "123456789* ..." para detectar fácilmente cualquier modificación en ella.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char full_name[10];
    char otra_area[50] = "123456789*123456789*123456789*123456789*123456789";
    printf("Enter your full name: ");
    fgets(full_name, 50, stdin);
    printf("Hellouda, %s", full_name);
    printf("Otra area, %s", otra_area);
    return 0;
}
```

Ejecución:

```
Enter your full name: juan perez cotapos valdez suber  
Hellouda, juan perez cotapos valdez suber
Otra area,  cotapos valdez suber
```

Análisis:

Le dijiste a `fgets` que dispone de 50 posiciones para almacenar el valor. Entonces, la función leyó y guardo el texto partiendo de la primera posición de `full_name`. Como esta variable solo tiene 10 posiciones, `fgets` sobrescribio los bytes que vienen a continuación.

Al primer `printf` le dices que la cadena comienza en `full_name`, y **sigue hasta encontrar un 0**. Esa es la razón por la que te imprime el nombre completo.

Ahora mira como quedo `otra_area`. Antes tenía "123456789* ...", pero su contenido se vio sobrescrito con lo que no cupo en `full_name`.

Eso se llama `buffer overflow`, un problema frecuente en C, y uno de los mecanismos de hackeo más comunes, pues no sólo puedes reemplazar valores, si no que también instrucciones.

Comment: Entonces, ¿los datos de la segunda variable son el overflow de la primera?

Comment: @ByRussX. Correcto ... en este caso. Qué viene a continuación de `full_name` solo lo sabe el compilador. Lo cierto es que terminaras escribiendo donde no debes y luego puede pasar cualquier cosa. Tampoco sabes cuando pasara. Tal vez de inmediato, tal vez un rato después, cuando intentes usar la variable sobreescrita, o quizás nunca, si sobreescribe algo que no se utiliza. Es un problema insidioso, pues puede manifestarse bastante lejos de donde ocurrió.